# UWP: How to remove image from memory?

Tags: c#, memory, uwp, bitmapimage

How to remove the previous image from memory?

Method for set image in images grid:

```cs
public async Task Show(KeyValuePair<Image, Storyboard> imageStoryboard)
{
    if (isVisible)
    {
        return;
    }
    isVisible = true;
    this.ImageComponent = imageStoryboard.Key;

    // элемент показан сохраняем его страницу
    Models.Page.Save(ImageData.Page, ImageData.NextPageLink);

    BitmapImage _bitmapImage = await GetBitmapImage(ImageData.ThumbnailUrl);

    // если высота неопределена вычисляем её
    if (Height == 0)
    {
        PixelHeight = _bitmapImage.PixelHeight;
        PixelWidth = _bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
        CalcHeight();
    }

    // параметры изображения
    ImageComponent.Width = App.Settings.side_size;
    ImageComponent.Height = Height - MARGIN;
    ImageComponent.Margin = new Thickness(0, MarginTop, 0, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(ImageComponent, Column);
    ImageComponent.DataContext = ImageData;
    ImageComponent.Source = _bitmapImage;

    // анимация
    imageStoryboard.Value.Stop();
    imageStoryboard.Value.Begin();
}
```

I set new source `ImageComponent.Source = _bitmapImage;` but how remove previous image from memory?
When i load more and more images memory is lost and appliaction close. And when i load previous images they load is so so fasted.

This method for load image: https://pastebin.com/AWHpNCJU

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly manipulate the memory, the application will periodically call the garbage cleanup GC.Collect to clean up unused resources. But this cleanup has a premise that the current object is no longer referenced. So please check if your image resources have not been released in time.

Here is the document about [Garbage Collection and Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/performance).

You can remove image files from the image cache by setting all associated `Image.Source` values to null.

In order to optimize memory usage, try to use `Uri` as the source of the image instead of `Stream`, which is the content of the document:

> To prevent images from being decoded more than once, assign image source property from Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) rather than using memory streams whenever you can. The XAML framework can associate the same Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in multiple places with one decoded image, but it cannot do the same for multiple memory streams even if they contain the same data.

For this, some examples are provided in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-animations-and-media#right-sized-decoding):

```cs
// use this
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
myImage.Source = bitmapImage;
bitmapImage.UriSource = new URI("ms-appx:///static/posts/cool-image.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

```cs
// not this
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new URI("ms-appx:///static/posts/cool-image.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
myImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

You also mentioned that memory will rise high when loading images. In this regard, you can use `DecodePixelWidth`/`DecodePixelHeight` to reduce the actual resolution of the image.

For example, if you get a 1080P image, but the size of the image control is only 100x100, if you do not modify the pixels of the image, it will cause unnecessary waste of resources. `DecodePixelWidth`/`DecodePixelHeight` can be used to limit the size of the image, which can effectively reduce the memory usage.

For more info on the Image class and performance, see [Optimize image resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-animations-and-media#optimize-image-resources).

> > When you are trying the above methods and still can't effectively reduce your memory, please check the memory usage through Visual Studio's debugging tool, and take a snapshot to compare and see which objects have been released. This is a document about [Use the Memory windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019).

Best regards.